# can't connent to any respository when I push the code to remote

Tags: eclipse, git

I am facing the issue "when I commit the code to local respository success,then I can't push the code from eclipse to git repository..."

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKySd.png]

How can I get past the error message

```
Can't connect to any repository: 
https://gitee.com/JinJiaoJingTong/SanPin.git 
(https://gitee.com/JinJiaoJingTong/SanPin.git: cannot open git-receive-pack)
```

Comment: Can't connect to any repository: https://gitee.com/JinJiaoJingTong/SanPin.git (https://gitee.com/JinJiaoJingTong/SanPin.git: cannot open git-receive-pack)

Comment: Show us the details of the error please.

Comment: you can click the img-link to see the detail  -Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any approved solutions so far ?

Answer (score 0):

As in [this article](http://blog.csdn.net/lglglgl/article/details/76796741), check the logs of Eclipse, and try:

> 1. Window-> preference-> Team-> Git-> configuration-> user setting to ensure that the user password is correct
> 2. window-preferences-General-Security- Secure Storage-Content
>      Find git items, clear it

Comment: I have checked the git config under your guidance,but this problem still exist..
Here are some other errores ,when I pull the code from git ,"cannot open git-upload-pack"  appearing.

Comment: @Leandy Did you find anything?

Comment: yeah! today it works well  when I restart the computer ,it is so strange，
thanks anyway,~_~

Comment: ok! I will remember,now I am a beginner  on the  stackoverflow.com